Update item in handlebars
I'm using handlebars and I want to make an update page with the value of each item from my database on the "value" field, as I kind of did with my stock display page
{{#each itens}}
<!-- Item N:{{@index}} -->
<div clas="padding">
    <ul class="list-group ms-3 me-3 mt-3 mb-3">
    <li class="list-group-item active">Desc: {{Descricao}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Quantidade: {{Quantidade}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">COD: {{Codigo}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Preco: {{Preco}}R$</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Preço de Compra: {{Pcompra}}R$</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lucro Liquido: {{Lucroliq}}R$</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lucro : {{Lucro}}%</li>
    <a href="/rotadeleteitem/{{id}}"><button class="btn btn-danger mt-2">Deletar</button></a>
    <a href="/edititem/{{id}}"><button class="btn btn-warning mt-2">Editar</button></a>
    </ul>
</div>
    <hr>
{{/each}}

In the {{#each itens}} block I can display the itens from my database.
How can I use data from my database without using the each segment (I need an individual reference for a single item in the database)?
here's how i tried to do:
<h1>Edição de item do estoque</h1>

<form action="/updateitem" method="POST">
    <p>Código</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{Codigo}}" name="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo  do Produto"> <br><br>
    <p>Descrição</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{Descricao}}" name="Descricao" placeholder="Descricao do Produto"> <br><br>
    <p>Quantidade</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{Quantidade}}" name="Quantidade" placeholder="Quantidade de itens"> <br><br>
    <p>Preço</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{Preco}}" name="Preco" placeholder="Preço do Produto"><br><br>
    <p>Preço de Compra</p>
    <input type="text" value="{{Pcompra}}" name="Pcompra" placeholder="Preço de Compra"> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" Enviar>
</form>



you are supposed to pass an object to the template when rendering... that's what you are doing also in the very first case where you are iterating over a list that you passed beforehand. You talk about items from my database but the those items are elements of a javascript array that is populated from your database at a previous step. You didn't share any detail about that step in your question so it's impossible to give a meaningful answer. How are you connecting to the database? How do you retrieve the object that you are supposed to pass to the template?

i want to pass the same object (itens) but i dont know how to pass a single one. you can se the full code on my github https://github.com/GiorgioRafael/ProjetoEstoque

Presumably you would use findOne to fetch a single record from your database instead of findAll.
